# a function to add the cumulative sum of multiple columns

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

Imagine a dataset that build of multiple numeric vectors and a couple of factor vectors like this one (made up for this purpose)

```
name <- c("tim", "tom", "ben", "mary", "jane")
sex <- c("male","male","male","female","female")
born <- c(1985, 1986, 1985, 1986, 1984)
v4 <- c(5,4,3,2,1)
v5 <- c(10,20,600,20,5)
v6 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
v7 <- c(0,0,20,4,60)
df <- data.frame(name, sex, born, v4,v5,v6,v7)
df[1:3] <- lapply(df[1:3], as.factor)
df[4:7] <- lapply(df[4:7], as.numeric)
```

I am using this function for cumulative sums of the numeric variables.

```
colCumsum <- function(x) {    
                  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) 
                  x[,i] <- cumsum(x[,i])
      x
    }
colCumsum(df[4:7])
```

It works fine, when i exclude numeric variables. But since **I need** factor variables, the original numeric variables and the cumulative sums **combined in one dataframe**, I tried to rewrite the function like this:

```
colCumsum2 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x) { 
                                            for (i in 1:ncol(x))
                                             {if (is.numeric(x[,i]) == F) {next}}
                                              #exlude non-numeric from function
                                              x[,i+ncol(n)-3] <- cumsum(x[,i])
                                              #add cumulative sum as extra column
                                              x 
                                           } )
```

My problem here: "new columns would leave holes after existing columns". And even if it worked, the number 3 is because of my knowledge of the number of factors (3) in the dataset and **needs to be generalized.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite `colColsum` like this:

```
colCumsum <- function(x) {
  check <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[paste0(names(x)[check], "_cumsum")] <- lapply(x[check], cumsum)
  x
}
```

Here it is used on your sample data:

```
colCumsum(df)
#   name    sex born v4  v5 v6 v7 v4_cumsum v5_cumsum v6_cumsum v7_cumsum
# 1  tim   male 1985  5  10  1  0         5        10         1         0
# 2  tom   male 1986  4  20  2  0         9        30         3         0
# 3  ben   male 1985  3 600  3 20        12       630         6        20
# 4 mary female 1986  2  20  4  4        14       650        10        24
# 5 jane female 1984  1   5  5 60        15       655        15        84
```

---

For reference, you can rewrite your loop to just focus on the numeric columns to get it to work:

```
colCumsum2 <- function(x) { 
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (is.numeric(x[, i])) {
      x[, paste0(names(x)[i], "_cumsum")] <- cumsum(x[, i])
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Comment: Nice to see a base R solution in the increasingly tidyverse-dominated field of data frame manipulation. +1

Comment: @AllanCameron, thanks. I appreciate what the tidyverse is trying to achieve, but I tend to stick to base or data.table. It's always good to see answers like yours to keep updated on different approaches.

Comment: @AllanCameron I love you ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `across` from `dplyr` here:

```r
library(dplyr)

colCumsum <- function(d) {
  mutate(d, across(where(is.numeric), ~cumsum(.x), .names = "cumsum_{col}"))
}

colCumsum(df)
#>   name    sex born v4  v5 v6 v7 cumsum_v4 cumsum_v5 cumsum_v6 cumsum_v7
#> 1  tim   male 1985  5  10  1  0         5        10         1         0
#> 2  tom   male 1986  4  20  2  0         9        30         3         0
#> 3  ben   male 1985  3 600  3 20        12       630         6        20
#> 4 mary female 1986  2  20  4  4        14       650        10        24
#> 5 jane female 1984  1   5  5 60        15       655        15        84
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `colCumsums` function in the `matrixStats` package. Just `cbind` the cumsums.

```
cbind(df, as.data.frame(matrixStats::colCumsums(as.matrix(df[nums]))))
#   name    sex born v4  v5 v6 v7 V1   V2 V3  V4
# 1  tim   male 1985  5  10  1  0  5   10  1   0
# 2  tom   male 1986  9  30  3  0 14   40  4   0
# 3  ben   male 1985 12 630  6 20 26  670 10  20
# 4 mary female 1986 14 650 10 24 40 1320 20  44
# 5 jane female 1984 15 655 15 84 55 1975 35 128
```